# XSLT debugging in Visual Studio error, could 'destabilize the runtime'

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, debugging, xslt

I was trying to debug some XSLT in Visual Studio based off of this MSDN article I found: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255602.aspx.

As soon as I tried to run it, I got this error:

### ﻿VerificationException

Operation could destabilize the runtime.

I've seen other StackOverflow questions for this error, but none that address it happening from debugging XSLT. Any ideas of how to get around it?

Comment: Best method is to comment out most of the code and then start adding in pieces until you find the error.  The xml serialization error message are vague and I've found that commenting out is best way of finding root cause.

Comment: It seems to not like the * in these pieces `<xsl:template match="*:section">`.

Comment: Where did you get the asterisk from?  Asterisk usually in a schema means more than one item and it the innertext and not against an attribute.

Comment: @Justin R, Do you mean that you have found the real reason for it? Is it related to the asterisk?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12071402/difference-between-and-node-in-xslt, maybe you could test it using the same sample from the MSDN document, or you could share your sample in your issue, of course, if it was resolved, you could share your solution as an answer.

Comment: The syntax `<xsl:template match="*:section">` (with a wildcard to match any namespace prefix) is only supported in XSLT 2.0 and above. If you are debugging in Visual Studio you are almost certainly using an XSLT 1.0 processor. Having said that, I would have expected a more meaningful error message in this case.

Comment: @TimC The transform I am working with is XSLT 2.0. Does that mean that Visual Studio doesn't offer support for debugging XSLT 2.0?

Comment: I believe that is the case. Microsoft has no love for XSLT 2.0 and their own XSLT processor (which I assume VS is using) is XSLT 1.0 only.

Comment: Good to know. Surprised Microsoft doesn't make an effort to offer support for it considering it's been around for a while.

Comment: Thanks for Tim C's assistance.@Justin R, It really has limitations for XSLT 2.0: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34596042/xsl-v-2-wont-work-in-visual-studio-2013

Comment: @Justin R, If this issue has been resolved, you could share your solution as an answer, and then mark it. If not, please feel free to share the latest issue.